# Using React proxy to fetch 2 different API

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, web, mongoose

I have a React app linked to the backend (Node.js) where I can make calls to the API. I used a proxy that points to my backend port, and now I need to add another proxy to fetch Cloudinary API.

I tried to declare proxy as an object but didn't work, also I tried the proxy-middleware method but nothing happened.

Thank you.